# How to Get Sales from Amazon account NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, amazon-mws

I'm trying to make an app so that you can login with your seller central account (like in the Amazon Seller app) and it shows you all your sales from each market combined into one screen, and to add a push notification feature so you get a notification for each sale. The problems I'm having are that I don't know how I'm supposed to get that info from Amazon. Would I use MWS? I can't find the part of the docs that shows you being able to just get total sales in numbers or currency over a certain time period, plus the NativeScript/NodeJS packages for MWS seem to be outdated. I have looked at the documentation, and the report seems to be a way to get this info, but I can't find which ReportType or whatever to request. Another thing is that I can't find a way to add a "Login With Your Seller Central Account and it just works" function instead of the user having to go to MWS, sign up, and type the Seller ID, Access Key etc...

My question is basically what API am I supposed to use, and a login feature for sellercentral (I looked at Login With Amazon, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.